# Talk to Chrome extensions background conscole via webdriver

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension

I am new to web programming. 
I am trying to add parameters to one of my Chrome extension.

I know I can enter, for example, "window.localStorage.setItem()" in the extension console. However, I cannot find a way to navigate my webdriver to that extension background page. I have seen, in the past, people would use chrome//extensions:extension_id as url to get to that page, but now this method seems not to work.

Is there any way that I can go to that page directly without telling my webdriver to click programmer mode and then click the extension?
Thanks in advance. This has been bothered me for hours.

Comment: when you say _chrome//extensions:extension_id_ you mean _chrome-extension://extension_id_, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry about the mistake

Answer (score 0):

Probably one thing to correct here is that `chrome://extensions/` opens up the ***Extensions*** on Chrome browser. So this shall work fine :

```
driver.get("chrome://extensions/")
```

Just a note now the ***chrome://extensions/extension_id*** does not take you to the extension page anymore.

---

In case you are interested in the *Details* or *Options* of an extension, you shall try and access it via the links only since the uri is not consistent for different extensions as well. e.g

> Extension 1
>   `chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/options/index.html`
>
> Extension 2 ::
>   `chrome-extension://fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg/options_pages/support.html`

The general format has `extension_id` but not certainly defines the entire uri to get you to the page.

---

I would suggest if you want to work around with the Extensions, there is this [Management API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management) which seems useful to dive in.

Comment: The extension I use creates a _generated_background_page.html. So if I driver.get() the url again, it will generate another page, which seems not correct (in fact, my extension stopped working.). Is there any way to avoid that? Thanks.

Comment: Probably the issue is due to the extension itself. Thank you very much

Comment: Have you solved this ? I'm looking for the same thing.

Comment: Having the same issue here. Doing a "get" on the _generated_backgroud_page.html results in a new instance of my extension.